# Puppet - How can I compare value of manifest variable against index from a loop in Template

Tags: ruby, puppet

Hi I'm trying to compare two values one value in manifest and other in a puppet template, How can I to this, I have tried the following it doesn't go into the If statement.

puppet.pp

```
$i = 0
$values = [val1, val2, otherval]

$var2 = template("/home/cluster/temp.erb")

notice ("This Current Location  ${var2}")
```

temp.erb

```
 <% @values.each_with_index do |this_server, idx| -%>

        <% if idx==@i -%>  #This is where I want to check

               If True!!!! 

        <% end -%>

               Out OF IFFF

 <% end -%>
```

How can I compare value of manifest variable against index from a loop in Template. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue after converting the value to an integer everything works fine.

The following was modified.

```
<% if idx==@i.to_i -%>
```

Comment: Exactly - Puppet 3.x has string values for all variables.